# Picasso Circle Transformation without Cropping Image

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, picasso

How do I make Circle Transformation without cropping the image? I've been trying for 2 days and I keep failing. This is the closest I've come so far, but as you can see, the image is not centered inside the circle.

```
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source,size-50, size-50,true);
    if (squaredBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size
            , source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    float r = size / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    squaredBitmap.recycle();
    return bitmap;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this `CircleImageView`:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menu1"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    app:border_color="@color/white"
/>
```

For more information: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView